# Tumblr theme css puzzle

Tags: css, tumblr

First off, let me apologise for the lack of SSCCE.  I don't really have enough expertise in this area to figure out what's relevant and what isn't.

In short, the problem is that on two different computers running the same resolution (1366x768), the top border (around the content) on my girlfriend's tumblr theme is off by about 1-3 pixels on one or the other screen.  We've tried using measurements in pixels, percentages and em but to no avail.  One system is running chromium on Ubuntu 11.10, the other is running Chrome on Windows 7.  At the moment, it's the Windows 7 system that's wrong.

Here's what it looks like on my screen:

[image: Example of misalignment]

Hopefully it's obvious what it should look like.

Here's the snippet that counts:

```
#header {
width: 650px;
height: 10px;
background: url('http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m7nz4c8UrU1rnrxu1o1_1280.png') no-repeat;
margin-left: 34.40em;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I'd like to draw particular attention to the margin-left rule as that is the rule that, if changed, affects the alignment of the border.

Finally, here's a pastebin link to the entire page, markup and all, in case there's something else that's relevant:
http://pastebin.com/MfxYgv0C

Comment: show us your site, and images with wrong and right behaviour of your design

Comment: The site is currently password-protected, there's no easy way to show the site other than as I did which is to paste the source code on pastebin.  Sorry.

Comment: Then make a dummy blog with some dummy posts and use the same theme. It's really difficult to figure out a problem like this without having a working example.

Comment: @ChrisBrowne if you can't show your blog, then please, give us the link to the theme in theme garden and include to the answer an image  with wrong and right behaviour of your design

Answer (score 0):

try to use wrapper div for header and content and set the left margin to wrapper.